# Uniqueness constraint not affecting fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel, activesupport

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :password
  attr_accessor :username, :password

  validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :password, :presence => true
end
```

Test:

```
  it "prevents username duplication" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: 'ted').should be_valid
    FactoryGirl.build(:user, username: 'ted').should_not be_valid
  end
```

I've confirmed that `User.count()` is 2. What am I missing with the uniqueness constraint?

Comment: Firstly, is your test failing?  `FactoryGirl.build` won't create a model, just build it in memory.  If you're getting `User.count == 2`, you likely already have another unrelated user in your database, can you check this?

Comment: To @PinnyM's point - perhaps in a `before(:each)` or `before(:all)` portion of the spec you're creating a User record, resulting in the count of `2`?

Comment: If I switch it to create, the user count becomes 2. Sorry, I meant when the record is properly saved I get 2.

The validation should affect the second built model, right? Regardless, my controller which is creating user objects definitely keeps creating users regardless of the username not being unique.

Comment: Try replacing the `FactoryGirl.build(...)` with `User.new(username: 'ted').valid?.should be_false`

Comment: @normalocity: still fails. I corrected to add the password as well, and it's coming back valid.

Comment: Is your app open source, and available for download (e.g. local testing)? It looks right as I'm reading it, but I'd like to try to spin up the app locally if you've got it up on GitHub or elsewhere.

Comment: Can you verify if the data inserted actually has the duplicate username?  Perhaps a before_validation hook is coming into play...

Comment: I just started on this, but if you want to checkout, it's here:

https://github.com/stefankendall/big-lifts-backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

attr_accessor breaks models. Get rid of that line.